# VS 2012 Debugging Averages 9 Minutes to Load Symbols

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, debug-symbols

I have a straight-up application -- no web services, or even calls to IIS, no UI, nothing -- just takes input data, munches it, then returns a result. Over the course of 15 trials, debug takes a little over **nine minutes(!)** to load the symbols before starting.

I've read every thread (I think) on SO about this issue, as well a numerous suggestions in the google-verse, to no avail. I've implemented what I could: disabled anything that looks like it's trying to call MS symbol servers, set symbols to load only specified modules, then specified nothing, made sure JIT compiling was enabled - and disabled, disabled source file exact match, etc. All to no avail.

I know this has something to do with my configuration, because nobody else is having the problem. I didn't have the problem until we upgraded to 2012 a couple of weeks ago.

Nine minutes to start debugging is simply unacceptable. Does anybody have a thought that might help?

Thanks!

Randy

Comment: Tools + Options, Debugging, Symbols.  Untick the symbol servers.  Talk to your LAN admin about network connectivity problems.

Comment: I did untick the symbol servers, pointed to a local directory, and set the cache to point to that directory.